# Using mdframed to format index entry

Tags: indexing, mdframed, imakeidx

I am trying to use an `mdframe` to format an index entry.  If I uncomment the `\def\UseMdframeForFormatting{}` in the MWE below (which attempts to use an `mdframe`), then I get the error:

> Use of \@index doesn't match its definition

### Code:

```
%\def\UseMdframeForFormatting{}%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{\subsection{#1}}

\newcommand*{\IndexWithName}[2]{%
    % #1 = word to index
    % #2 = index name
    \index[#2]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand*{\FormatIndexEntry}[1]{%
    \ifdefined\UseMdframeForFormatting% <--- If this is defined, things no longer work
        \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=0.5\linewidth]
            \textcolor{red}{#1}%
        \end{mdframed}%
    \else
        \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \fi
}%


\NewDocumentCommand{\AddIndexEntry}{%
    O{}% #1 = index name
      m% #2 = word to index this under
      m% #3 = indexed term
}{%
    \expandafter\IndexWithName\expandafter{%
        #2!\FormatIndexEntry{#3}%
    }{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\indexopt}[2]{\index[#2]{#1}}

\makeindex[title={Main Index},columns=1,program=texindy]
\makeindex[title={Name Index},columns=1,program=texindy,name=Name]
\indexsetup{level=\section}

\begin{document}

%% This works fine here, but not above to format index entry
\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=0.5\linewidth]
    \textcolor{red}{foo}%
\end{mdframed}%

\AddIndexEntry[Name]{zero}{zero sum}

\clearpage 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
%\printindex
\printindex[Name]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\protect\begin{mframed}` etc.? But this will leave a `missing item` error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with `mdframed` but with `tcolorbox`, this is working, if `\begin{tcolorbox}` is `\protect`ed. The style of the `tcolorbox` should be adapted with `\newtcolorbox` actually.

```
\def\UseMdframeForFormatting{}%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{\subsection{#1}}

\newcommand*{\IndexWithName}[2]{%
  % #1 = word to index
  % #2 = index name
  \index[#2]{#1}%
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\FormatIndexEntry}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{UseMdframeForFormatting}{% <--- If this is defined, things no longer wor
    \textcolor{red}{#1}%
  }{%
    \protect\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe={gray},nobeforeafter,box align=center,sharp corners,width=0.5\linewidth]%
      \protect\textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \protect\end{tcolorbox}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddIndexEntry}{%
    O{}% #1 = index name
      m% #2 = word to index this under
      m% #3 = indexed term
}{%
  \expandafter\IndexWithName\expandafter{%
    #2!\FormatIndexEntry{#3}%
  }{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\indexopt}[2]{\index[#2]{#1}}


\makeindex[title={Main Index},columns=1,program=texindy]
\makeindex[title={Name Index},columns=1,name=Name,program=texindy]
\indexsetup{level=\section}

\begin{document}

%% This works fine here, but not above to format index entry
\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=0.5\linewidth]\textcolor{red}{foo}\end{mdframed}%

\AddIndexEntry[Name]{zero}{zero sum}
%\index[Name]{zero}

\clearpage 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
%\printindex
\printindex[Name]
\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\def\UseMdframeForFormatting{}%

\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{\subsection{#1}}

\newcommand*{\IndexWithName}[2]{%
  % #1 = word to index
  % #2 = index name
  \index[#2]{#1}%
}%

\newtcolorbox{indexentrybox}[1][]{%
  nobeforeafter,
  boxrule=0.5pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  box align=center,
  sharp corners,
  colframe={gray},
  coltext={red},
  colback=white,
  #1,
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\FormatIndexEntry}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{UseMdframeForFormatting}{% <--- If this is defined, things no longer wor
    \textcolor{red}{#1}%
  }{%
    \protect\begin{indexentrybox}
      #1%
      \protect\end{indexentrybox}
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddIndexEntry}{%
    O{}% #1 = index name
      m% #2 = word to index this under
      m% #3 = indexed term
    }{%
      \expandafter\IndexWithName\expandafter{%
        #2!\FormatIndexEntry{#3}}{#1}%
    }
\newcommand{\indexopt}[2]{\index[#2]{#1}}


\makeindex[title={Main Index},columns=1,program=texindy]
\makeindex[title={Name Index},columns=1,name=Name,program=texindy]
\indexsetup{level=\section}

\begin{document}
Foo

\AddIndexEntry[Name]{zero}{zero sum}
\clearpage 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
%\printindex
\printindex[Name]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, this works. Although in my application I needed to include `\usepackage{morewrites}`.  If an `mdframed` specific solution does not show up I'll switch to `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I'll try to provide for `mdframed` as well, but I suspect, there's something going wrong *after* `\endmdframe`. I could not figure out yet

Comment: I guess you ran into difficulties with mdframed version?

Comment: @PeterGrill: I did not pursue -- sorry, I was busy with other things recently. Shall I go on?

Comment: Nah, if you are busy with other things thats ok. I guess I could play around with `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I am a `tcolorbox` user by heart, but I am not satisfied with the 'solution' (a bypass, rather) so I'll try to find another one.